# Using django-widget-tweaks with Jinja2 template engine

Tags: django-forms, jinja2, django-widget-tweaks

I'm using django v1.11.7 with Jinja2 v2.10 as the template engine.

In my website, I wish to render forms using bootstrap. I found out that [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) can be used for this integration.

This package won't work with Jinja templates, since it needs to load a custom tag set into the Jinja environment. Loading tag sets can be complex, since I may need to write an extension.

Is there an easy way to get django-widget-tweaks to work with Jinja? Or is there another way for integrating boostrap with Jinja?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little late but maybe this can help.

What I did is import the function I wanted to use and called them in my jinja templates:

**app_root.jinja2.py**

```
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2 import contextfunction

from widget_tweaks.templatetags.widget_tweaks import render_field


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'render_field': render_field,
    })
    return env
```

**In template**

```
{% set class = class + "my-html-class" %}
{{ render_field(field, class) }}
```

**EDIT**: Anyone with a little bit of Jinja and template tag experience knows this won't work. For my current needs, I defined the two following function in my jinja config and will evaluate my needs at a later time.

```
def set_attr(bound_field, attr, value):
    bound_field.field.widget.attrs[attr] = value
    return bound_field

def add_class(bound_field, value):
    try:
        bound_field.field.widget.attrs['class'] += value
    except KeyError:
        bound_field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = value
    return bound_field
```

**EDIT 2**
Other useful link: https://github.com/niwinz/django-jinja/issues/140

To make this solution work, I had to make these changes:
**jinja2.py**

```
from jinja2 import Environment
from widget_tweaks.templatetags.widget_tweaks import add_class
from widget_tweaks.templatetags.widget_tweaks import set_attr


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.filters['set_attr'] = set_attr
    env.filters['add_class'] = add_class
    return env
```

**template.html**

```
{{ form.field |set_attr('attr:val') }}
{{ form.field |add_class('my_class') }}
```